# Undoing "marked as read" status of emails fetched with imaplib

Tags: python, email, imaplib

I wrote a python script to fetch all of my gmail. I have hundreds of thousands of old emails, of which about 10,000 were unread.

After successfully fetching all of my email, I find that gmail has marked all the fetched emails as "read". This is disastrous for me since I need to check all unread emails only.

How can I recover the information about which emails were unread? I dumped each mail object into files, the core of my code is shown below:

```
m = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com")
m.login(user,pwd)
m.select("[Gmail]/All Mail") 
resp, items = m.uid('search', None, 'ALL')
uids = items[0].split() 
for uid in uids:
    resp, data = m.uid('fetch', uid, "(RFC822)") 
    email_body = data[0][1]
    mail = email.message_from_string(email_body)
    dumbobj(uid, mail)
```

I am hoping there is either an option to undo this in gmail, or a member inside the stored mail objects reflecting the seen-state information.

For anyone looking to prevent this headache, consider this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10991533/imaplib-gmail-how-to-download-full-message-all-parts-while-not-marking-read). This does not work for me, however, since the damage has already been done.

Edit:
I have written the following function to recursively "grep" all strings in an object, and applied it to a dumped email object using the following keywords:

```
regex = "(?i)((marked)|(seen)|(unread)|(read)|(flag)|(delivered)|(status)|(sate))"
```

So far, no results (only an unrelated "Delivered-To"). Which other keywords could I try?

```
def grep_object (obj, regex , cycle = set(), matched = set()):
    import re
    if id(obj) in cycle:
        return 
    cycle.update([id(obj)])
    if isinstance(obj, basestring):
        if re.search(regex, obj):
            matched.update([obj])

    def grep_dict (adict ):
        try:
             [  [ grep_object(a, regex, cycle, matched )  for a in ab ] for ab in adict.iteritems() ]
        except:pass

    grep_dict(obj)
    try:grep_dict(obj.__dict__)
    except:pass
    try:
        [ grep_object(elm, regex, cycle, matched ) for elm in obj ]
    except: pass
    return matched

grep_object(mail_object, regex)
```

Comment: Do you still have the file dumps you produced from your code?

Comment: I do, but I have no idea where a "seen" flag may have been stored. I am currently writing a recursive "grep" of an arbitrary python object to try to find something containing relevant strings (eg "seen" "read" etc) but I should probably look into documentation instead

Comment: @ShashankGupta Do you happen to know where this "seen" information is stored within the objetc?

Comment: Sorry no I don't. Wish I could help you. :\

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a similar problem (not with gmail), and the biggest problem for me was to make a reproducible test case; and I finally managed to produce one (see below).

In terms of the `Seen` flag, I now gather it goes like this:

- If a message is new/unseen, IMAP fetch for `\Seen` flag will return empty (i.e. it will not be present, as related to the email message).
- If you do IMAP select on a mailbox (INBOX), you get a "flag" `UNSEEN` which contains a list of ids (or uids) of emails in that folder that are new (do not have the `\Seen` flag)
- In my test case, if you fetch say headers for a message with `BODY.PEEK`, then `\Seen` on a message is not set; if you fetch them with `BODY`, then `\Seen` is set
- In my test case, also fetching `(RFC822)` doesn't set `\Seen` (unlike your case with Gmail)

In the test case, I try to do `pprint.pprint(inspect.getmembers(mail))` (in lieu of your `dumpobj(uid, mail)`) - but only after I'm certain `\Seen` has been set. The output I get is posted in [mail_object_inspect.txt](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ca72cf845d0d75027981) - and as far as I can see, there is no mention of 'new/read/seen' etc. in none of the readable fields; furthermore `mail.as_string()` prints:

```
'From: jesse@example.com\nTo: user@example.com\nSubject: This is a test message!\n\nHello. I am executive assistant to the director of\nBear Stearns, a failed investment Bank.  I have\naccess to USD6,000,000. ...\n'
```

Even worse, there is no mention of "fields" anywhere in the `imaplib` code (below filenames are printed if they do not contain case-insensitive "field" anywhere):

```
$ grep -L -i field /usr/lib/python{2.7,3.2}/imaplib.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/imaplib.py
/usr/lib/python3.2/imaplib.py
```

... so I guess that information was not saved with your dumps.

---

Here is a bit on reconstructing the test case. The hardest was to find a small IMAP server, that can be quickly ran with some arbitrary users and emails, but without having to install a ton of stuff on your system. Finally I found one: [trivial-server.pl](https://github.com/bestpractical/net-imap-server/blob/master/ex/trivial-server.pl), the example file of Perl's [Net::IMAP::Server](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Net-IMAP-Server/lib/Net/IMAP/Server.pm); tested on Ubuntu 11.04.

The test case is pasted in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/940ba305737195e0682b), with two files (with many comments) that I'll try to post abridged:

- [trivial-serverB.pl](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/940ba305737195e0682b/raw/4a0bdcdbb61afe17a17adb01b75197087cef03cc/trivial-serverB.pl) - Perl (v5.10.1) `Net::IMAP::Server` server (has a terminal output paste at end of file with a telnet client session)
- [testimap.py](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/940ba305737195e0682b/raw/47e737106501eb2871da902ecebb4fc5073bb1d1/testimap.py) - Python 2.7/3.2 `imaplib`
  client (has a terminal output paste at end of file, of itself operating with the server)

### trivial-serverB.pl

First, make sure you have `Net::IMAP::Server` - note, it has many dependencies, so the below command may take a while to install:

```sh
sudo perl -MCPAN -e 'install Net::IMAP::Server'
```

Then, in the directory where you got `trivial-serverB.pl`, create a subdirectory with SSL certificates:

```sh
mkdir certs
openssl req \
  -x509 -nodes -days 365 \
  -subj '/C=US/ST=Oregon/L=Portland/CN=localhost' \
  -newkey rsa:1024 -keyout certs/server-key.pem -out certs/server-cert.pem
```

Finally run the server with administrative properties:

```
sudo perl trivial-serverB.pl
```

Note that the `trivial-serverB.pl` has a hack which will let a client to connect without SSL. Here is `trivial-serverB.pl`:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use v5.10.1;
use feature qw(say);
use Net::IMAP::Server;

package Demo::IMAP::Hack;
$INC{'Demo/IMAP/Hack.pm'} = 1;

sub capabilityb {
  my $self = shift;
  print STDERR "Capabilitin'\n";
  my $base = $self->server->capability;
  my @words = split " ", $base;
  @words = grep {$_ ne "STARTTLS"} @words
    if $self->is_encrypted;
  unless ($self->auth) {
    my $auth = $self->auth || $self->server->auth_class->new;
    my @auth = $auth->sasl_provides;
    # hack:
    #unless ($self->is_encrypted) {
    #  # Lack of encrpytion makes us turn off all plaintext auth
    #  push @words, "LOGINDISABLED";
    #  @auth = grep {$_ ne "PLAIN"} @auth;
    #}
    push @words, map {"AUTH=$_"} @auth;
  }
  return join(" ", @words);
}

package Demo::IMAP::Auth;
$INC{'Demo/IMAP/Auth.pm'} = 1;
use base 'Net::IMAP::Server::DefaultAuth';
sub auth_plain {
    my ( $self, $user, $pass ) = @_;
    # XXX DO AUTH CHECK
    $self->user($user);
    return 1;
}

package Demo::IMAP::Model;
$INC{'Demo/IMAP/Model.pm'} = 1;
use base 'Net::IMAP::Server::DefaultModel';
sub init {
    my $self = shift;
    $self->root( Demo::IMAP::Mailbox->new() );
    $self->root->add_child( name => "INBOX" );
}

###########################################
package Demo::IMAP::Mailbox;
use base qw/Net::IMAP::Server::Mailbox/;
use Data::Dumper;

my $data = <<'EOF';
From: jesse@example.com
To: user@example.com
Subject: This is a test message!

Hello. I am executive assistant to the director of
Bear Stearns, a failed investment Bank.  I have
access to USD6,000,000. ...
EOF
my $msg = Net::IMAP::Server::Message->new($data);
sub load_data {
    my $self = shift;
    $self->add_message($msg);
}
my %ports = ( port => 143, ssl_port => 993 );
$ports{$_} *= 10 for grep {$> > 0} keys %ports;

$myserv = Net::IMAP::Server->new(
    auth_class  => "Demo::IMAP::Auth",
    model_class => "Demo::IMAP::Model",
    user        => 'nobody',
    log_level   => 3, # at least 3 to output 'CONNECT TCP Peer: ...' message; 4 to output IMAP commands too
    %ports,
);

# apparently, this overload MUST be after the new?! here:
{
no strict 'refs';
*Net::IMAP::Server::Connection::capability = \&Demo::IMAP::Hack::capabilityb;
}

# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27206371/printing-addresses-of-perl-object-methods
say " -", $myserv->can('validate'), " -", $myserv->can('capability'), " -", \&Net::IMAP::Server::Connection::capability, " -", \&Demo::IMAP::Hack::capabilityb;

$myserv->run();
```

### testimap.py

With the server above running in one terminal, in another terminal you can just do:

```
python testimap.py
```

The code will simply read fields and content from the one (and only) message the server above presents, and will eventually restore (remove) the `\Seen` field.

```py
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3: # python 2.7
  def uttc(x):
    return x
else:                       # python 3+
  def uttc(x):
    return x.decode("utf-8")
import imaplib
import email
import pprint,inspect

imap_user = 'nobody'
imap_password = 'whatever'
imap_server = 'localhost'
conn = imaplib.IMAP4(imap_server)
conn.debug = 3

try:
  (retcode, capabilities) = conn.login(imap_user, imap_password)
except:
  print(sys.exc_info()[1])
  sys.exit(1)

# not conn.select(readonly=1), else we cannot modify the \Seen flag later
conn.select() # Select inbox or default namespace
(retcode, messages) = conn.search(None, '(UNSEEN)')
if retcode == 'OK':
  for num in uttc(messages[0]).split(' '):
    if not(num):
      print("No messages available: num is `{0}`!".format(num))
      break
    print('Processing message: {0}'.format(num))

    typ, data = conn.fetch(num,'(FLAGS)')
    isSeen = ( "Seen" in uttc(data[0]) )
    print('Got flags: {2}: {0} .. {1}'.format(typ,data, # NEW: OK .. ['1 (FLAGS ())']
            "Seen" if isSeen else "NEW"))

    print('Peeking headers, message: {0} '.format(num))
    typ, data = conn.fetch(num,'(BODY.PEEK[HEADER])')
    pprint.pprint(data)

    typ, data = conn.fetch(num,'(FLAGS)')
    isSeen = ( "Seen" in uttc(data[0]) )
    print('Got flags: {2}: {0} .. {1}'.format(typ,data, # NEW: OK .. ['1 (FLAGS ())']
            "Seen" if isSeen else "NEW"))

    print('Get RFC822 body, message: {0} '.format(num))
    typ, data = conn.fetch(num,'(RFC822)')
    mail = email.message_from_string(uttc(data[0][1]))
    #pprint.pprint(inspect.getmembers(mail))

    typ, data = conn.fetch(num,'(FLAGS)')
    isSeen = ( "Seen" in uttc(data[0]) )
    print('Got flags: {2}: {0} .. {1}'.format(typ,data, # NEW: OK .. ['1 (FLAGS ())']
            "Seen" if isSeen else "NEW"))

    print('Get headers, message: {0} '.format(num))
    typ, data = conn.fetch(num,'(BODY[HEADER])') # note, FLAGS (\\Seen) is now in data, even if not explicitly requested!
    pprint.pprint(data)

    print('Get RFC822 body, message: {0} '.format(num))
    typ, data = conn.fetch(num,'(RFC822)')
    mail = email.message_from_string(uttc(data[0][1]))
    pprint.pprint(inspect.getmembers(mail)) # this is in mail_object_inspect.txt
    pprint.pprint(mail.as_string())

    typ, data = conn.fetch(num,'(FLAGS)')
    isSeen = ( "Seen" in uttc(data[0]) )
    print('Got flags: {2}: {0} .. {1}'.format(typ,data, # Seen: OK .. ['1 (FLAGS (\\Seen))']
            "Seen" if isSeen else "NEW"))

    conn.select() # select again, to see flags server side
    # * OK [UNSEEN 0] # no more unseen messages (if there was only one msg in folder)

    print('Restoring flag to unseen/new, message: {0} '.format(num))
    ret, data = conn.store(num,'-FLAGS','\\Seen')
    if ret == 'OK':
      print("Set back to unseen; Got OK: {0}{1}{2}".format(data,'\n',30*'-'))
      print(mail)

      typ, data = conn.fetch(num,'(FLAGS)')
      isSeen = ( "Seen" in uttc(data[0]) )
      print('Got flags: {2}: {0} .. {1}'.format(typ,data, # NEW: OK .. [b'1 (FLAGS ())']
              "Seen" if isSeen else "NEW"))

conn.close()
```

### References

- [How do I mock an IMAP server in Python, despite extreme laziness?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351656/how-do-i-mock-an-imap-server-in-python-despite-extreme-laziness)
- [Get only NEW Emails imaplib and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13210737/get-only-new-emails-imaplib-and-python)
- [Undoing "marked as read" status of emails fetched with imaplib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18678827/undoing-marked-as-read-status-of-emails-fetched-with-imaplib/27201941#27201941)
- http://www.skytale.net/blog/archives/23-Manual-IMAP.html
- [IMAP FETCH Subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12490648/imap-fetch-subject)
- https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2009-March/527020.html
- http://www.thecodingforums.com/threads/re-imaplib-fetch-message-flags.673872/